# CSS with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to do something like this, but it's doesn't work

```
 window.onresize = center;

 function center() 
 {
      var x=window.innerWidth;
      x = x/2;
      document.getElementById("center_div").style.marginLeft = x;
 }
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Please define what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: What are you trying to do with your code? Can you explain it?

Comment: as far as I know, that is an invalid function call, you need to include the brackets, ie center();. You may have to create an event listener for the window resize too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add `px`, `Element.style.marginLeft` do not accept numbers. It should be valid CSS property (`margin-left`) value; It can be `10px` or `5%` or `auto`;

```
document.getElementById("center_div").style.marginLeft = x + 'px';
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine, but missing one thing. You have to put "px" after the X variable. In other word, it should be:
 `document.getElementById("center_div").style.marginLeft = x+"px";`
Otherwise, the browser will not know its unit.

I made a sample in jsfiddle, this would be a working example. Try it. http://jsfiddle.net/TLPak/

PS. I've updated the code to include the window.onresize in it. (And some improvement, the DIV's width considered.) http://jsfiddle.net/TLPak/1/  Trigger it by click event or on window resize event are both OK. Hope it has some help to you.

```
function center() {
    var x=window.innerWidth;    
    x = x/2;

    var y = document.getElementById("center_div").offsetWidth;
    y = y/2;

    document.getElementById("center_div").style.marginLeft = x - y + "px"; 
}

window.onresize = center;
```

Comment: This doesn't center the object, it puts the top left corner of the object into the center. You need to update the margin left

Comment: OK, I revised the code. It will work on window resize event now.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the css property `margin: auto` . Random example (not mine): http://bluerobot.com/web/css/center1.html . Additonally, you'll want `width: 50%` . Is that what you're looking for? Let me know, and I'll change my answer if need be. :)

Comment: He wants to use javascript